# When is it dangerous to have too many dynamic arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, disjoint-sets

I'm currently writing code for an assignment that deals with cities and bridges. I have to print the cities and bridges out in their respected districts such as:

```
//unorganized inputs from user given the # of "paths" we need
4       // the # of paths
1 2 5  // 1 = city , 2 = city, 5 = bridge length
6 7 5  // 6 = city , 7 = city, 5 = bridge length
2 3 7  // 2 = city , 3 = city, 7 = bridge length
6 9 7  // 6 = city , 9 = city, 7 = bridge length
```

After run through program, it will be sorted as:

```
first district
1 2 5
2 3 7

2nd district
6 7 5
6 9 7
```

Now, I'll be reading these inputs through cin. I want to store all the possible paths such as 1 2 5 into an array and then sort and organize them through the program. The problem is that I may have over 500,000 paths from the user. I want to create 500k dynamic arrays. Will this cause serious problems in terms of memory?

I have looked at other possible ways of solving this such as kruskal's algorithm and disjoint sets(I think is the most useful). I'm having a very hard time understanding the coding of disjoint sets, I figured I try a way I'm more familiar with.

Any help with where to store the values and compare and organize them would be great. Links to places where I read info on this would help. I've read a lot over the past few days. Hasn't helped much.

To sum it all up, my questions are:

- Will 500k dynamic arrays cause serious problems in terms of memory?
- Where to store the values and compare and organize them given the paths?

Comment: "The problem is that I may have over 500,000 paths from the user.", do you imply that you want the user to input 500k paths through the console?

Comment: this is will probably be through a file.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: It is most likely that the tutor will use something like `cat problem_instance1 | user_written_program`.

Comment: @Zeta, I hoped for it, but thought I'd better ask to be sure ;)

Comment: Why use dynamic arrays when you have `std::vector`?

Comment: not allowed to use any STL. forgot to mention it up there

Comment: Am I missing something here or do your 500k records all have the same 3 element structure? This would of course eliminate the need for any dynamic arrays for those in contrast to a simple 3-member struct.

Comment: @ChristianRau Your correct. The inputs will only be 3 numbers in length. I've used the struct, but I think my lack of knowledge of OOP and inheritance is limiting my ability to implement it effectively. Any resources you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

> Will 500k dynamic arrays cause serious problems in terms of memory?

No problem there, assuming each is merely an array of 3 ints. Typically, you would avoid doing this as separate allocations because it is excessive -- it will be a bit slow and the bookkeeping required will consume a fair amount of memory too. There's a better approach:

> Where to store the values and compare and organize them given the paths?

I'd start with a struct/class which holds those 3 fields, then use a `std::vector` of those. This will store all your values as one contiguous allocation. Very fast to create, search and allocate in comparison.

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention, I'm not allowed to use anything in STL. Everything has to be coded by myself.

Comment: @Chris then you can use an array of those 500k records (or however many you will need) to accomplish the equivalent of `vector`. just avoid allocating it on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

In general, assuming that you have 2 gigs of memory for your app, 500K records of 12 bytes (assuming you use 32bits for your values) will not be a problem.
If you wish to reduce your data set size, you can, for example, use data format like:

```
struct {
   unsigned short city_a;
   unsigned short city_b; 
   char length;
}
```

Look at the size of the city set (number of cities), and maximum length between two cities. 
Also, things like indexing city pairs (A-B becomes Pair_ID) can reduce the data set as well.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be directly related to your question, but I think what you are trying to accomplish is this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory). And if you model your graph as an adjacency matrix, you need not allocate 500k dynamic arrays . Consider the following format for storing your data :

```
int city_map [MAX_NO_OF_CITIES][MAX_NO_OF_CITIES];

city_map[i][j] = length_of_brigde_connecting_city_i_to_j;
```

This way storing 500,000 entries will only take a little more than 1MB of memory.